# PHP filter_require_array is failing

Tags: php, filter-input

I got an AJAX file which can get an array as POST variable. The array looks like this:

```
array(
    'NAME' => PRICE,
    'NAME2' => PRICE2
)
```

For example, here's a var_dump about one possibility: (`var_dump($_POST['additions'])`)

```
array(2) {
    ["vloer"]=>
    string(5) "50.00"
    ["dak"]=>
    string(5) "20.00"
}
```

To filter the array, I use the following line:

```
$additions = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'additions', FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);
```

To my shock, it returns false for some reason. I tried `filter_input_array` as well which didn't work. Even without the `FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY` it didn't work.

Comment: Your POST variables doesn't seems to contain any 'additions' values. So why it's not normal that filter_input returns false when you call it ?

Comment: It does? As I said, the var_dump on $_POST['additions'] clearly returns values. So it does contain additions.

Comment: Okay, do you want to validate each fields in additions ?

Comment: var_dump(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'additions', FILTER_DEFAULT , FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY));

Comment: @bxN5 Thanks that worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're filtering float values (prices) I'd recommend to filter those with the flag `FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION` as `FILTER_DEFAULT == FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW` and you can end up with an undesired injection in the input.

```
$additions = filter_input( 
                 INPUT_POST, 
                 'additions', 
                 FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, 
                 FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY + FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION
);
```

I split the parameters in separate lines just for easier reading here :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, didn't really think of this. Deserves a cookie. Will accept answer.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @bxN5 ([PHP filter_require_array is failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42645075/php-filter-require-array-is-failing#comment72417280_42645075)):

Changing

```
$additions = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'additions', FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);
```

Into

```
$additions = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'additions', FILTER_DEFAULT , FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY));
```

Did the job.